# Store temporarily the name of a file in the session

Tags: php, forms, symfony, session

I have a form which contains also an *input* of type *file*. This form is connected to an entity, as it's done in the official Symfony tutorials, where a "form type" is created to connect a entity and a form.

I had a problem whenever I needed to update an entity through its form, mostly because of the input file.

The idea was just to allow the user to eventually upload a new file (without involving the previously uploaded file, i.e. the old file was not supposed to be returned to the client somehow, also because I didn't know how to do it in this environment/situation...).

Then, in the controller, I could check if the user had uploaded a new file, and if yes, then I could remove the old one. If not, I should reset the field which stores the name of the uploaded file to be the name of the "old" file. In both cases, I need to keep track of the name of the "current" file, before returning the form to edit the entity. I did this by storing it in the session.

I don't know how good or bad is this idea, maybe because, after reading so many articles, etc, about sessions I still don't have a clear idea about them. I know it's a way to make HTTP requests state-full, but I still don't have a clear idea of the implementation, i.e. what's happening exactly under the hood.

Sessions could also be cleared or terminate, but I don't know in which situations. So, I don't know how dangerous or risky is to store the name of the old/current file in the session.

Could you please explain why should it be a good or bad idea? And if a bad idea, what's a better alternative?

---

If you're interested, this is the corresponding relevant code:

```
...

// store old brochure in the session,
// so that if the user doesn't upload a new file
// we use the old file
if(isset($product) && $request->isMethod('GET')) {
  $this->get('session')->set($product->getId(), $product->getBrochure());
}

$editForm = $this->createForm(ProductType::class, $product, ['brochure_required' => false]);
$editForm->handleRequest($request);

// remove previous file if a new file was uploaded
if($request->isMethod('POST')) {
    if(isset($request->files->get('product')['brochure'])) {

      $filePathToDelete = $this->getParameter('brochures_directory') . '/' . $this->get('session')->get($product->getId());

      if(is_file($filePathToDelete)) {
        unlink($filePathToDelete);
      }

    } else {
      $product->setBrochure($this->get('session')->get($product->getId()));
    }

  $this->get('session')->remove($product->getId());
}

...
```

Comment: Do these files are stored in the filesystem? If so, I think you need to persist their names (in database for example). And with foreign keys you can know which file is already uploaded for that specific parent entity.

Comment: for anyone interested: file upload http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/upload_file.html. also transformers http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html Transformers mostly to avoid logic in controller